# Selecting and calling specific parameter in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Using the library panadas, I am able to read a csv and print the values of a specific column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv",encoding='latin1')
print(df[['num_1]])
```

The dataframe below is a sized down version of my csv file.

[My dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INlED.png)

I want to be able to go to column `Describe` filter by **The start of journey** and then print the values of  `num_1`

The output should then shows these numbers

```
58,14,526,52,352
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a [minimal reproducable exampe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with the input data you are using rather than linking screenshots. I suppose the sequence in the dataframe is maintained and that you want to have all values of `num_1` until a value other than `"The start of journey"` occurs in `Describe`?

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, if given picture shows your `csv` file, then after reading the file using your command the dataframe should be like this:

```
+-----+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
|     | name  |       Describe        | num_1  | num_2  |
+-----+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
|  0  | er    | The Start of Journey  |    17  |  249.5 |
|  1  | NaN   | NaN                   |    58  |   51.0 |
|  2  | NaN   | NaN                   |    14  |   66.5 |
|  3  | NaN   | NaN                   |   526  |   84.0 |
|  4  | be    | The end of journey    |     3  |   13.0 |
|  5  | tg    | Levels                |   342  |   34.0 |
|  6  | NaN   | NaN                   |   231  |   55.6 |
|  7  | NaN   | NaN                   |    23  |   75.0 |
|  8  | tf    | counts                |    54  |   34.6 |
|  9  | sf    | The Start of Journey  |    52  | 4324.0 |
| 10  | gd    | The Start of Journey  |   352  |   54.0 |
+-----+-------+-----------------------+--------+--------+
```

To get the desired output, which for some reason **does not include 17** you can use:

```
df['Describe']=df['Describe'].ffill()
df[df['Describe']=='The Start of Journey']['num_1'][1:]
```

**Output:**

```
1      58
2      14
3     526
9      52
10    352
Name: num_1, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I have tried your code but for some reason as you said it is not talking the first value . is there any solution regarding that ?

Comment: if you want to read the first value use `df[df['Describe']=='The Start of Journey']['num_1']`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df[df['Describe']=='The start of journey']['num_1'].values
```

The above line filters the dataframe based on filtering condition. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection)

Comment: did you try that? that's invalid syntax

Comment: this will not give all values of num_1 column, it's only giving [17,52]

Comment: Ok in that case, I am not sure how the filtering is required. If it is saying get values if value is not `The start of journey`, then the output does not make sense. Can you clarify ?

Comment: i think you'd need a `ffill` if `Describe` is not an index, however needs clarification

Comment: if you have noticed the image attached in the first post called My_dataframe, after looking that I thought, this could require MultiIndex, concept, the user @mandi wants all the values which come under the hierarchy of "**The Start of  journey**" ,i .  which is a root for num_1 column values.

Comment: @anky_91, can you please help me on how I would achieve that ? would appreciate it a lot

Comment: @TheGuy, Yes as you also said it, I want all the vaues of  ```num_1``` from ```The Start of journey```

Comment: @The Guy, any input regarding the question ?

Comment: @The Guy, the csv file is created from one of my python codes

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing your data through python code, then i would do like this,through MultiIndex.

```
import pandas as pd

outer=['The Start','The Start','The Start','The Start','The Start','Levels','The Start','X','X','The Start'] #This will be  outer index i.e is 'Describe'

inner=[1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1,2,1]   #inner index for outer elements, example first 5 'The Start ' values of outer object maps with first 5 integers of inner object.

index_hierarchy=list(zip(outer,inner)) # zipping (outer and inner) to combine them together

data=[17,58,14,526,3,2,24,1,2,889] # data which we want to add in 'num1' column

index_hierarchy=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_hierarchy)  #setting the hierarchy like , print the index_hierarchy to see the result

df1=pd.DataFrame(data,index=index_hierarchy,columns=['num1'])
df1.index.names=['Describe','Indexes'] # set the name for the columns
df1
```

**Ouput before storing dataframe in csv file**

```
                   num1
Describe Indexes    
The Start   1       17
            2       58
            3       14
            4       526
            5       3
Levels      1       2
The Start   1       24
X           1       1
            2       2
The Start   1       889
```

Now to get expected output:

```
df1.to_csv('Book1.csv') # saving dataframe to csv 'Book1.csv'
book1_csv=pd.read_csv('Book1.csv',index_col=[0,1]) # read 
print(book1_csv)
final_ouput=book1_csv.loc['The Start']['num1']
final_ouput.reset_index()['num1']
```

**Final output**

```
[17, 58, 14, 526, 3, 24, 889]
```

**Notes:**

1. I have used different data, you can replace that.
2. if you have 5 back to back values in '**num1**' for '**The Start**' value then in outer object you have to mention '**The Start**' value  for five times times and so on for others, **example**:

   outer=['The Start','The Start','The Start','The Start','The Start']

3.Now in **inner** object i have created a sequence for 'The Start' like [1,2,3,4,5] for the each 'The Start' value.

4.Now after 'The Start', next value is 'Levels' which occurs for one time so it has 1 in **inner** object

Comment: I was just asking once I load the already existing csv file like this ```df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Desktop/Plot/output.csv', delimiter=";", encoding='unicode_escape')``` and then filter by a string and show the values from num_1